# Embedded jetty - class loading common libraries

Tags: java, jetty

I'm using Embedded jetty server. I have few web apps and I'm starting it. But all my web apps having same set of 10 jar files in WEB-INF/lib.

Is there any way that I can configure my embedded jetty server to load the classes into mem at one time and use it when required.

Please correct me, if my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. I need to set classpath of all the common jars in the Application which is starting the Web Apps, and I can remove the lib folder from war file.